# Separate adress-chunk: making 3 columns out of one

Tags: regex, hex

i have a spreadsheed in calc. with some records. There is a column that contains the following information

```
Ecole Saint-Exupery
Rue Saint-Malo 24
67544 Paris
```

Well i need to have those lines divided into at least three columns

```
name: Ecole Saint-Exupery
street: Rue Saint-Malo 24
postal code and town 67544 Paris
```

Or even better - i have divided the postal code and town into two seperate columns!?
Question: is this possible? Can (or should) i do this in calc (open document-formate)?
Do i need to have to use a regex and perl or am i able to solve this issues without an regex?

Note - finally i need to transfer the data into MySQL-database...

I look forward to a tipp...

greetings

**BTW:** you can see all the things in a real world-live-demo: http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=a&a=50&s=1750 - see the filed

```
Schulname
Straße
PLZ Ort
```

These field contains three things - the name, the street and the Postal Code and the town!
Question: can this be divided into parts!? If you copy and paste the information - and drop it to calc then you get all the information in only one cell. How to divide and seperate all those information into three cells or even four?

BTW - i tried to translate the information to hex-code - see the follwoing...:

```
Staatl. Realschule Grafenau 
Rachelweg 20
94481  Grafenau  

00000000: 53 74 61 61 74 6C 2E 20  52 65 61 6C 73 63 68 75
00000010: 6C 65 20 47 72 61 66 65  6E 61 75 20 0A 52 61 63
00000020: 68 65 6C 77 65 67 20 32  30 0A 39 34 34 38 31 20
00000030: 20 47 72 61 66 65 6E 61  75 20 20
```

but i do not know if this helps here!??

Can you help me to solve the problem. Do i need to have a regex!?

Many thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a regex. You should be able to take the contents of the cell in question and split it up using the newline character that is present. I am not familiar with calc, but if there is a split() or explode() function that returns an array, then splitting on a newline will yield the 3 pieces you are looking for.

Comment: hello dingonv, many many thanks for he quick answer! I have to have a closer look if there is a split or explode function that gives back an array. You mean that i can force Calc to make an array out of the string!? That would be great! I would b e glad if i can do this with the calc-programme! egyptcoder

Comment: i did a quick search and found this link to the openoffice forums: http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=33218&start=0   . instead of splitting on a space as in the example there, try splitting on "\n" or "\r" and see what you get. those are the 2 standard escape strings for newlines (and carriage return)

Comment: hello dingonv - mille grazie. I love your idea. I guess that your tipp is very clever.  At the moment i am not at home [i am downtown in a internetcafe, but i will do  the adviced things later tonight] I come back and report all the findings. Greetings - Egyptcoder